Having trouble with AdMob after upgrading to Expo version 51
I have upgraded my Expo project to version 51 and now am getting an error when creating an aab build for the Play Store. It is as follows:
FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-google-mobile-ads:compileReleaseKotlin'.



A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction


Compilation error. See log for more details....
I've tried re-installing moblie ads by running npm install --save react-native-google-mobile-ads and clearing the cache but this has not worked. How can I fix this error?

How is this related to AdMob?

Actually I found that AdMob wasn't the problem I thought something was wrong with   my configuration for the ads. I just needed to upgrade to the latest version of react-native-google-mobile-ads and now everything works fine. I ran npm install react-native-google-mobile-ads thinking this would install the newest version but I needed to run npm install react-native-google-mobile-ads@latest

This solved it: npm install react-native-google-mobile-ads@latest
